# Save Naive Bayes Trained Classifier in NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, nltk, naivebayes

I'm slightly confused in regard to how I save a trained classifier. As in, re-training a classifier each time I want to use it is obviously really bad and slow, how do I save it and the load it again when I need it? Code is below, thanks in advance for your help. I'm using Python with NLTK Naive Bayes Classifier.

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
# look inside the classifier train method in the source code of the NLTK library

def train(labeled_featuresets, estimator=nltk.probability.ELEProbDist):
    # Create the P(label) distribution
    label_probdist = estimator(label_freqdist)
    # Create the P(fval|label, fname) distribution
    feature_probdist = {}
    return NaiveBayesClassifier(label_probdist, feature_probdist)
```

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of persistence strategy? As in save to DB, file and load again? You could just pickle the data and load it again later.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To save:

```
import pickle
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, f)
f.close()
```

To load later:

```
import pickle
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: how would I go about it if I want to retrain my model using an already pickled model?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             import pickle
f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
.....then?

Comment: I get `TypeError: can't pickle module objects`

Answer (score 5):

I went thru the same problem, and you cannot save the object since is a ELEFreqDistr NLTK class. Anyhow NLTK is hell slow. Training took 45 mins on a decent set and I decided to implement my own version of the algorithm (run it with pypy or rename it .pyx and install cython). It takes about 3 minutes with the same set and it can simply save data as json (I'll implement pickle which is faster/better).

I started a simple github project, check out the code [here](https://github.com/luke14free/sentipy)

Comment: Thanks @luke14free, do you have an documentation how to use it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To Retrain the Pickled Classifer :

```
f = open('originalnaivebayes5k.pickle','rb')
classifier = pickle.load(f)
classifier.train(training_set)
print('Accuracy:',nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,testing_set)*100)
f.close()
```