# Save naive bayes classifier nltk

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I am having trouble pickling a naive bayes classifier trained via nltk.  Here is the code I am using to save the classifier:

```
pickledfile=open('my_classifier.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(classifier,pickledfile)
pickledfile.close()
```

This seems to work ok.  However, when I try and load the pickled file using the following code:

```
f1=open('my_classifier.pickle')
classifier=pickle.load(f1)
f1.close()
```

I get an EOF error.  I got this code straight from this question and it doesnt work for whatever reason for me: [Save Naive Bayes Trained Classifier in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017086/save-naive-bayes-trained-classifier-in-nltk).  Let me know if you know what is going on with this.

Comment: I had some trouble with this, too. Dumping and loading with the `cPickle` module worked for me. If it doesn't work either, try setting the protocol to 1: `pickle.dump(classifier, pickledfile, 1)`

Comment: Yes, setting then protocol parameter fixes similar problems with MaxEnt models.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the environment setup to test out your code, but I have the feeling it's not right in the part where you save/load the pickle.

Referring to the [Storing Taggers](http://nltk.org/book/ch05.html) section of the NLTK book, I would change your code and do it like this:

```
def save_classifier(classifier):
   f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
   pickle.dump(classifier, f, -1)
   f.close()

def load_classifier():
   f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
   classifier = pickle.load(f)
   f.close()
   return classifier
```

Hope it helps.

From
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17635668/